# Sorting depending on coordinate value

Tags: java

I've been trying to sort an `ArrayList` of coordinates depending on the value of X. so far i've been able to sort either ascending or descending, but that's for everything inside the `ArrayList`. if I try to put the ordering inside 2 if's that check if the value is even or odd I always get a `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error. How do I go further from this point? This is the code I have so far:

```
package TSP.TSP_Algo;

import TSP.Coordinate;
import TSP_Algorithm;

import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Convex extends TSP_Algorithm {
    private ArrayList<Coordinate> coords;
    private ArrayList<Coordinate> sortedCoords = new ArrayList<>();

    public Convex(ArrayList<Coordinate> coords) {
        this.coords = coords;
        ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinaten = this.coords;
    }

    public ArrayList<Coordinate> getSortedCoordinates() {

        ArrayList<Point> Points = coordToPoint(coords);
        for (Point points : Points) {
            Coordinate Even = new Coordinate(0, 0);
            Coordinate Odd = new Coordinate(0, 0);
            if (points.x % 2 == 0) {
                Points.sort(new PointYAscending());
                Points.sort(new PointXAscending());
                Even.x = points.x;
                Even.y = points.y;
                sortedCoords.add(Even);
            }
            if (points.x % 2 != 0) {
                Points.sort(new PointXDescending());
                Points.sort(new PointYDescending());
                Odd.x = points.x;
                Odd.y = points.y;
                sortedCoords.add(Odd);
            }
        }
        return sortedCoords;
    }
    private ArrayList<Point> coordToPoint(ArrayList<Coordinate> coords) {
        ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Coordinate coord : coords) {
            points.add(new Point(coord.x, coord.y));
        }
        return points;
    }
    public class PointXAscending implements Comparator<Point> {
        public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
            {
                return Integer.compare(a.x, b.x);
            }
        }
    }
    public class PointXDescending implements Comparator<Point> {
        public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
            {
                return Integer.compare(b.x, a.x);
            }
        }
    }
    public class PointYDescending implements Comparator<Point> {
        public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
            {
                return Integer.compare(b.y, a.y);
            }
        }
    }
    public class PointYAscending implements Comparator<Point> {
        public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
            {
                return Integer.compare(a.y, b.y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your code is of the form:

```
for (Point points : Points) {
    //...
    Points.sort(new PointYAscending());
    //...
}
```

Firstly, logically this does not make sense. "For each point, sort all of the points." Why? You only need to call `sort` once.

Secondly, this is not legal. You cannot modify a list while you are looping over it. `sort` is modifying the structure of the list, making it impossible to correctly iterate over it, thus throwing an exception.

---

Your code should probably be:

```
ArrayList<Point> points = coordToPoint(coords);
points.sort(new PointXAscending().thenComparing(new PointYAscending()));
return points;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to *modify* (sort) a list while *iterating* over it. This is not allowed. You need to remove the following lines from your code:

```
        Points.sort(new PointYAscending());
        Points.sort(new PointXAscending());
```

repeated twice.